# Node.js backend images are saved but after restarting the container they are gone

Tags: node.js, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a problem. With the help of `multer` I save the images on my backend server in a special folder.
However, the problem is that as soon as the server restarts, the pictures are gone. Is there a way to rewrite the CI/CD pipeline or the gitlab runner so that the images remain?

```yaml
stages:  
  - build
  - deploy
  
build docker image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - docker rmi -f ci/backendcontainer
    - docker build -t ci/backendcontainer .
  only:
    - main

deploy docker image:
  stage: deploy
  script:    
    - docker-compose up -d
  only:
    - main
```

```js
router.put('/post/photo/:id', auth_util.checkSession, upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params
        const imagePath = req.file.path
        const description = req.file.originalname
        await pgclient.query(`UPDATE public.tbl_player
            SET playerimageurl='${imagePath}'
            WHERE playerid= ${id};`);
        console.log("ADDING NEW IMAGE")
        res.status(200).json(imagePath);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(404);
    }
})
```

Example with multer

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const pgclient = require("../app");
const auth_util = require("../utilities/auth_util");
const Knex = require("knex");

const knex = Knex({
    client: "pg",
    connection: {
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    },
});

const fs = require("fs");
const eis = require("ejs");
const sharp = require("sharp");

const multer = require('multer')
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'images')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, `${Date.now()}-${file.originalname}`)
    }
})


router.put('/post/photo/:id', auth_util.checkSession, upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {

    try {
        console.log(req.body)
        const { id } = req.params
        const imagePath = req.file.path
        const description = req.file.originalname
        //console.log(id)
        await pgclient.query(`UPDATE public.tbl_spieler
            SET spielerbildurl='${imagePath}'
            WHERE spielerid = ${id};`);
        console.log("ADDING NEW IMAGE")
        res.status(200).json(imagePath);
        //res.send({ description, imagePath })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(404);
    }
})

router.delete('/delete/photo/images/:filename/:id', auth_util.checkSession, async (req, res) => {
    const { filename } = req.params;
    const { id } = req.params;
    const filePath = `images/${filename}`;
    try {
        await pgclient.query(`UPDATE public.tbl_spieler
                SET spielerbildurl = ${null}
                WHERE spielerid = ${id};`)
        fs.unlink(filePath, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to delete image' });
            }
            return res.json({ success: true, message: 'Image deleted successfully' });
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(404);
    }
});




router.get("/get/photo/:id", auth_util.checkSession, async (req, res, next) => {
    const { id } = req.params
    try {

        player = await pgclient.query(`SELECT spielerbildurl
        FROM public.tbl_spieler
        WHERE spielerid = ${id};`)
        res.status(200).json(player.rows[0]);
        //console.log("hat gerklappt")
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(400).send();
    }
});

router.get('/images/:imageName', (req, res) => {
    // do a bunch of if statements to make sure the user is 
    // authorized to view this image, then
    try {
        const imageName = req.params.imageName
        console.log(req)
        console.log("----")
        console.log(imageName)
        const readStream = fs.createReadStream(`images/${imageName}`)
        readStream.pipe(res)
    }
    catch {

    }

})

const path = require("path");

router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});












module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Typically with (Docker) containers, any files you don't want to lose should be kept in a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) (and you'd configure `multer` to store the image files on it). Not sure how that works combined with Gitlab, though.

Comment: That is a very good idea. Thank you.
Do you know how to create this volume? 
And access granted ?

Comment: You typically use [`volumes`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose) in `docker-compose.yml`, but I have no idea if that will work in your particular context.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a directory locally and map that through a volume in your docker-compose configuration.

> Volumes are the preferred mechanism for persisting data generated by
> and used by Docker containers. While bind mounts are dependent on the
> directory structure and OS of the host machine, volumes are completely
> managed by Docker.
> https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

you can try the below

```
stages:  
  - build
  - deploy
build docker image:
stage: build
script:
- npm install
- docker rmi -f ci/backendcontainer
- docker build -t ci/backendcontainer .
only:
- main

deploy docker image:
stage: deploy
script:
- docker-compose up -d
volumes:
- images:/home/node/app/images
only:
- main
```

for the express app just make sure that you use the `images` directory. the volume will keep the container in sync with whatever happens to that directory.

Comment: I created a volume. `volumes: - images:/home/node/app/images`. But how can I connect now this with multer ? I would be great if you create a code snippet.

Comment: Thank you. But why could I not create tthe `volumes` inside the docker ?

Answer (score 0):

CI/CD runners are meant as a way to rerun periodic jobs in the scope of a project, so it's common to delete any used context by a job (or you risk running out of disk), or they get deleted/recreated. Think of them as throwaway servers.

If you want to save generated images imho the best recommendation is to save them outside the runner space, eg cloud storage (AWS S3). Docker volumes will persist your changes locally once you're done with your container, but they won't save you from the runner being nuked.

Comment: Thanks. I read that too. But the question is how do I connect the volume to my multer. Please see my comment above. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68846357/upload-files-from-express-js-and-multer-to-persistent-docker-volume

Comment: This is what my docker-compose looks like ` volumes: - ./images:./usr/src/app/images/            - ./newspaper:./usr/src/app/newspaper/` `nvalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: 'usr/src/app/images' mount path must be absolute`

Comment: use absolute path on the left hand side part. SO ./images:/usr/src/app/images/ will map this to root /usr/src/app/images in the container

Comment: you tell multer to use `/usr/src/app/images` as you would if you ran the app directly on your workstation